Need for post-analysis after logistic regression?
I am studying a cohort of 3200 patients with a number of risk factors for a postoperative complication. I have done a logistic regression in R and refined my regression with the step() function. I have thus identified several highly significant risk factors. One of them being fluid balance. It is known that too much fluid as well as too little fluid may promote the complication, but what I've from R is that for every 100ml extra fluid the likelihood for complication is increased by 0.03 (estimate). P=0.001.
Do I need some sort of post analysis regarding this?

No, because there's no post analysis that can correct the errors introduced by using stepwise variable selection. These have been discussed here many times. They are similar for logistic reg. and OLS:
Standard errors are too small
p values are too small
Parameter estimates are biased away from 1 (in OLS, they are biased away from 0).
It stops you from thinking.
Ideally you would use substantive knowledge to select variables, but, if you must use an automated method, LOESS isn't bad.

Ok but still, if I suspect that this independent variable (fluid balance) could affect at both high values and large negative values (but maybe not inbetween), how should I go about demonstrating that?

Then you should have started out differently, using a spline of fluid balance.
